# how to select HTML tag ID in JQUERY when is ID is repeating in PHP loop

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
<input type="text" class='collapse' value='<?= $pst_id; ?>' id='postIdPay'>
```

id='postIdPay' this tag is in loop and repeating if the condition is true.  Condition is getting true many times, Because of this the ID of this tag is no more unique. So while i am selecting the ID of this tag in jquery it not working and giving me error that ID in not unique, It requires unique id.

can i do this id='postIdPay?= $pst_id; ?' ? and how can i get this id in JQUERY ?

Comment: Maybe something like this? If you want the inputs to be unique for w/e reason, and if `$pst_id` is unique :) `id='postIdPay_<?= $pst_id; ?>'>`

Comment: ID's must be unique - that's the rule and you can't do anything about it. Use class instead

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement. What you want to do after selecting the element by id in jquery? Perhaps, it can be fulfilled by class.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy if i do this id='postIdPay_<?= $pst_id; ?>'> then this id will be unique you are right. but how i will target this id in jquery

Comment: I've no idea how and where are you using jquery in this instance, is it a form? More details please

Comment: @SupritamSadhukhan i want to display its value on bootstrap modal and then i will insert value in mysql database

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy jquery code is not in loop, Code  is in the last.

Comment: @subhan Are you trying to display the value of one/first tag/field with id postIdPay or all of them?

Comment: in loop {there is <a> tag which trigger bootstrap modal which have multiple radio buttons. each radio button shows a specific distinct login from} .  the behaviour of radio button is controled by  jqury <-- out of loop.

Comment: Can you please sanitize and add the code of the jquery which is trying to use input - postIdPay?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

 $("#calAmountCheck").click(function () {
  
  $("#checkToShow").show("slow");
  $("#checkTome").hide("slow");
  $("#balanceDiv").hide("slow");
 

 });
 $("#notApplicable").click(function () {

  $("#checkToShow").hide("slow");
  $("#balanceDiv").hide("slow");
  $("#checkTome").show("slow");


 });
 $("#balanceTrans").click(function () {

  $("#checkToShow").hide("slow");
  $("#checkTome").hide("slow");
  $("#balanceDiv").show("slow");



 });

Comment: @Supritam please have look the code added above

Comment: @subhan the jquery code does not utilize  the the input tag with id postIdPay. Can you please edit the original post to add the jquery script part which uses the input with id "postIdPay"? Please add the code which gives you error that ID in not unique.

Comment: <input type="text" class='collapse' value='<?= $pst_id; ?>' id='postIdPay'>                        The above code is in while(any-condintion){<input type="text" class='collapse' value='<?= $pst_id; ?>' id='postIdPay'>  } when the condition is true many times then this code will be also executed many times as well. in this case we have multiple input fields with same id. i am thinking to bind row id with input field id "id='postIdPay?$id'" but this how i will get in in JQUERY?